# What is the difference between "cost for" and "cost"?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between "cost for" and "cost"?

For example:

> 1) Building a sophisticated website costs $100 for me.
>
> 2) Building a sophistacated website costs me $100.

Put another way, what is the difference between:

> How much does it cost **for** you?

and:

> How much does it cost you?

Answer (score 1):

There is an implied gerund in "for".

- The cost for [eating] an apple is being kicked out of Eden.
- The cost of an apple is being kicked out of Eden.

In American english, both work, but stick with "of".

Good luck, 
G.

Comment: Not, the object of the preposition here is "me", not "building the website".

Answer (score 0):

*"How much does it cost for you?"* is **not natural**. But *to cost someone something* is perfectly correct:

> Building a sophisticated website costs me $100.
>
> Unemployment costs the taxpayer billions each year.
>
> It cost me a fortune!

Answer (score 0):

Both forms have the same meaning (although I believe you will hear "cost me $100", not "costs"). There may be more emphasis in the "for me" construction that the price is not fixed, but specific to me (i.e. you may not get the same price). This difference is not a rule, though.